# Iteration through rows of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading data from an excel sheet using pandas and then iterating through the data using df.iterrows(), processing it further to automate a work flow using python/selenium.

Each row of my spreadsheet belongs to job applicants and their attributes are getting captured in different columns. However, since a person can have multiple degrees their educational details are captured in columns as degree1, specialation1, college1, degree2, specialiation2, college2 etc. Maximum 5 qualifications can be filled in. During iteration i want to breakout and then loop through rows of education (degree, specialation, college) for one person.

How to accomplish this task?

I am attaching a github link of the sample data for reference [text](https://github.com/harishmani09/iteration-prob) which basically has the same data as is pasted below ...

```
sr_no   old_emp_id  name    address mobile  degree1 specialisation1 college1    degree2 specialisation2 college2    degree3 specialisation3 college3    emp_status
0   1   24  Amit    ABC Road    356363474   Computer Science    Robotics    IIT Delhi   MSC ML  MIT PHD AI  Harvard full-time
1   2   34  Samit   Xyz Road    367474748   Bachelor of Arts    Economics   Delih Univ  Masters of Eco  Internatioal Relation   Delhi Univ  PHD Foreign Trade   Delhi Univ  part-time
2   3   56  Richard PTC Street  363637677   Bsc Biology Mumbai Univ Masters of Science  Microbiology    Mumbai Univ PHD Communicable disease    Mumbai Univ part-time
```

I tried grouping it using a custom function presented below. But it does not give the desired results.  :

```
def group_attributes_diff(df):
    new_data =[]
    for i in range(0, len(df),35):
        candidate_info={}
        for j in range(i,i+7+1):
            row = df.iloc[j]
            
            degree_name = row['degree_name' + str(int(j-i)//7+1)]
            specialisation = row["specialisation" + str(int(j - i)//7 + 1)] if "specialisation" + str(int(j - i)//7 + 1) in row else None
            course_start_date = row["course_start_date" + str(int(j - i)//7 + 1)] if "course_start_date" + str(int(j - i)//7 + 1) in row else None
            course_end_date = row["course_end_date" + str(int(j - i)//7 + 1)] if "course_end_date" + str(int(j - i)//7 + 1) in row else None
            marks_grades = row["marks_grades" + str(int(j - i)//7 + 1)] if "marks_grades" + str(int(j - i)//7 + 1) in row else None
            university = row["university" + str(int(j - i)//7 + 1)] if "university" + str(int(j - i)//7 + 1) in row else None
            course_type = row["course_type" + str(int(j - i)//7 + 1)] if "course_type" + str(int(j - i)//7 + 1) in row else None
            education={
             "degree_name":degree_name,
                "specialisation":specialisation,
                "course_start_date":course_start_date,
                    "course_end_date":course_end_date,
                    "marks_grades":marks_grades,
                    "university":university,
                    "course_type":course_type
                            }
        
            candidate_info["Education "+str(int(j-i)//7+1)] = education
        new_data.append(candidate_info)
    return pd.DataFrame(new_data)

test_df = group_attributes_diff(df.copy())

print(test_df.to_excel('education.xlsx'))
```

Thanks in advance for your inputs!
Harish

Comment: What is the expected output supposed to look like?

Comment: i want data for degree, specialisation and college respectively for a person say amit to be stacked like a table.

Comment: `name address mobile       degree      specialisation college
              Amit ABC Road 3563634.     Computer Science Robotics IIT Delhi
                                             MSC                   ML                  MIT
                                             PHD                    AI                  Harvard`

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend learning data structures and how you can pivot and unpivot data. Here's an example of how I would do this:

Once you've read the excel sheet with pd:

```
df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
```

Then you unpivot the data:

```
df_unpivoted = pd.melt(df, 
                       id_vars=['sr_no', 'old_emp_id', 'name', 'address', 'mobile', 'emp_status'],
                       var_name='attribute', 
                       value_name='value')
```

You'll get a resulting structure like this:

```
sr_no   old_emp_id  name    address mobile  emp_status  attribute   value
0   1   24  Amit    ABC Road    356363474   full-time   degree1 Computer Science
1   2   34  Samit   Xyz Road    367474748   part-time   degree1 Bachelor of Arts
2   3   56  Richard PTC Street  363637677   part-time   degree1 Bsc Biology
3   1   24  Amit    ABC Road    356363474   full-time   specialisation1 Robotics
4   2   34  Samit   Xyz Road    367474748   part-time   specialisation1 Economics
5   3   56  Richard PTC Street  363637677   part-time   specialisation1 None
6   1   24  Amit    ABC Road    356363474   full-time   college1    IIT Delhi
7   2   34  Samit   Xyz Road    367474748   part-time   college1    Delih Univ
8   3   56  Richard PTC Street  363637677   part-time   college1    Mumbai Univ
9   1   24  Amit    ABC Road    356363474   full-time   degree2 MSC ML
10  2   34  Samit   Xyz Road    367474748   part-time   degree2 Masters of Eco
11  3   56  Richard PTC Street  363637677   part-time   degree2 Masters of Science
12  1   24  Amit    ABC Road    356363474   full-time   specialisation2 MIT
13  2   34  Samit   Xyz Road    367474748   part-time   specialisation2 Internatioal Relation
14  3   56  Richard PTC Street  363637677   part-time   specialisation2 Microbiology
```

Now you can build logic around the unique attributes.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. This looks interesting , i will try this on my code and update you with results